# Draft, Publish and versioning of resource with REST

Tags: rest, web-services

I am developing a webservice where all the intermediate changes should be versioned(Drafts), And users can publish (Live their changes). For users to keep referring older versions (for let's say compatibility reasons.) users should be able to get older states as well.

Here is how my current design looks like

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      action      |                  request                  |                            response                          |                state of resource                |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| create a post    | post                                      | status=201 id=123 and version=v1                             | resource created with version v1                |
| update the post  | put with id=123 and version=v1            | status=200 id=123 and version=v2                             | new version of resource created with version=v2 |
| update the post  | put with id=123 and version=v2            | status=200 id=123 and version=v3                             | new version of resource created with version=v3 |
| update the post  | put with id=123 version=v1                | status=409 and body indicating user is editing stale version |                                                 |
| publish the post | put with id=123 version=v2 action=publish | status=200 id=123 version=p1 (p indicating published)        | new version created with version=p1             |
| get all versions | get list with id=123 status=all           | status=200 and v1,v2,p1 in the body                          | no change                                       |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Does the above follow rest architecture?
The particular issues I am worried about are

1. Here Put is not idempotent since it ends up creating a new version every time we do it.
2. User has to be aware of action=Publish for publishing the article. is it ok to have this information at client side IMO in the response body of put/get/post we should tell all the operations that are supported something like this

```
{
  "body": {...}
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "publish",
      "uri": "/order/123/publish"
    },
    {
      "type": "save",
      "uri": "/order/123/save"
    },
    {
      "type": "archive",
      "uri": "/order/123/archive"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Is there anything I am missing

Is it overly pedantic about details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using a hateoas-style approach, I would recommend the following:

1. Have one uri that always represents the latest version. For instance `/order/123`.
2. Create links with relation types from [RFC5829](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829) to other versions. Examples: `version-history`, `latest-version`, `predecessor-version`, `successor-version`. Use just the link relations that you need. Different versions are simply different resources.
3. Instead of using an `action`, you can mark a resource as either `public` or `draft` using a property (for example `isPublic`). If set to true, that version becomes the public version. The last  'version' with that status would become the one that's really 'live'.

**Solving the PUT idempotency issue**

Given that `PUT` creates a new 'version' every time you run it, is it still idempotent? I think this becomes a little tougher to answer. Is the effect of 2 PUT requests the same as just doing 1?

Well if you consider HTTP access logs, 2 identical PUT requests will also cause 2 entries. I don't really know how to reconcile this, but my thinking is:

1. 2 identical PUT requests still creates the intended state. An update to the main resource. There is now an extra (versioned) resource, but maybe that doesn't really matter?
2. You could opt to *not* create a new version of the resource if it hadn't actually changed, circumventing this completely.

Comment: I'd argue that for designing such a system, there will be a certain form of authorization management available where draft links are only returned to users having permissions to change the resource to a public one, any other users on the other hand will only be aware of the public resources. To change the resource to a public one the server only needs to include the URI in further requests. Internally a flag whether the resource is public or not might be enough to decide whether to include the link in a response also respecting the requesting user of course.

Comment: In regards to `PUT` having side-effects, [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) explicitly states a sample that it can be used to create a new version and similar to GIT only move the HEAD to the most current version. +1 for mentioning the version link-relations though :)